# Symfony: I cannot use a route name starting with "web" string

Tags: php, symfony, web, routes

I've used a route name as "webmaster" (www.domain.com/webmaster) and symfony shows me an error like:

> NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET master"

And my htacces is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /web/app.php  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I know, "web" is reserved keyword in a Symfony2 Application. How i use this exception in my project.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us how your route is defined. In `routing.yml` or with annotation in your controller?

Comment: Check your routes. Try `php app/console router:debug` to see if the route you are looking for is configured.

Comment: I don't have a static route as "webmaster". It's dynamically generated in a controller. For example: path: /{category}

Answer (score 3):

Symfony's `web` directory should be your site's document root, and as such, does not need to be included in the path as the base of your rewrite rule.

So, assuming your `.htaccess` file is located at `PROJECT_ROOT/web/.htaccess` then all that should be required is this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
```

Again, this assumes that you've set up Apache to point to `PROJECT_ROOT/web` as the site's document root (where `PROJECT_ROOT` would be something like `/var/www/vhosts/symfony_project`)

Answer (score 0):

Reacting to your comment

> I don't have a static route as "webmaster". It's dynamically generated in a controller. For example: path: /{category}

I guess you need to add a prefix to your route. 
In exemple, how can symfony know if `www.myapp.com/admin` is a route one of your dynamic route or a standard route?
You need to have at least a prefix like `/site/{category}`